# JqueryUI CDN works fine if my site is running on my local drive but won't load on my ipage host

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use JqueryUI's accordion widget on my page, the widget works fine on my local drive.  However, when I uploaded my page on ipage host, the website won't load the JqueryUI.

Here is my CDN links to Jquery and JqueryUI:

```
<!-- jQuery library 1.1.2-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!--JQUERY UI CDN-->
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any errors in your browser's JavaScript / Network console? Can you provide a link to the non-working site?

Comment: http://mzprojects.net/about.html

Comment: Here is the site's web address, this should be shown with JqueryUI's accordion widget.

Comment: Well, for starters, you don't have any code calling `.accordion()`. See https://jqueryui.com/accordion/. Did you forget to upload an updated JS file?

Comment: Phil... THATS IS IT!! OMG I can't believe I forgot to update my js file to the host.  I owe you a beer.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're loading jQuery twice. Try the following

```
<!-- always load CSS first -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">

<!-- jQuery library 1.11.2-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--JQUERY UI from Google CDN-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I've removed the `http:` schemes from the URLs so they will load securely if your page is also secure.

You'll also notice I've used Google's CDN for all resources. You should be able to use jQuery's if you really want to though.

---

And as always, don't forget to upload **all** updated files to your webhost. I recommend `rsync`.

Comment: This is good resource, however, same thing happen with my older links: It only works on my local computer, but won't load after I upload them to my ipage host website.

Answer (score 0):

That is conflict, don't define same library. You have jquery minified (jquery.min.js) and you have jquery-1.11.2.js. Which one do you choose. and ensure jquery on the top of jquery ui, because jquery is dependency of jquery ui. I hope helpful.